# Troubleshooting OSError: out of pty devices

Tags: python, linux, pty

From time to time I'm getting an OSError exception with the message 'out of pty devices' when calling `pty.openpty()` (it's happening when a bunch of instances of my scripts run concurrently).

What is the limit that I'm hitting?  How can I get around this?

CentOS 5.6, Python 2.4

Answer (score 10):

In my Ubuntu Linux, the max number of open ptys is given by:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pty/max
```

This value is configurable in:

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
```

All this info, and much more can be found in:

```
man pty
```

Comment: Mine is set to 4096, and I'm the only one using my server. I still get this error. Why?

Answer (score 6):

Same issue is raised when `devpts` is not mounted, usually in chroots, to mount `devpts` device type:

```
mount -t devpts none /path/to/chroot/dev/pts
```